# Update app with new certificate in Microsoft Private UWP Store

Tags: uwp, certificate, windows-10-universal, appx, appxmanifest

I created an UWP app in our Microsoft Private Company Store, but with a wrong certificate.

Now I would like to upload a new Package to this app with the correct Certificate.

I created a new appxupload with a link to the correct certificate in the appxmanifest. But when I try to upload this the dev store gives me 2 errors:

- Invalid package family name
- Invalid package publisher name

Does anyone have an idea on how to change an existing app in the private store to use a completely different certificate?

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone have an idea on how to change an existing app in the
>   private store to use a completely different certificate?

Please note that for the LOB app distributed via Windows Store for business, you're not able to change the certificate provided by Store. If you replace the Store certificate with a new one, you won't be able to submit the package to Dev Center as your package with different package family name and publisher name cannot be recognized by Dev Center.

If you need to replace the certificate, you can only distribute the app via sideloading.

For more details, [Sideload LOB apps in Windows 10](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=623433).

Comment: So, just for my understanding, if we want to use the Windows Business Store to distribute an LOB app to our colleagues we have to use the certificate that comes from the Store itself? @mattew